# Access the same function name but in different file

Tags: shell

I am working on Shell Scripting.
I want to use the same function name but in different file.

i.e

**A_sh Contains:-**

```
  showPid()
  {
      echo "File A_sh"
  }
```

**B_sh Contains:-**

```
  showPid()
  {
      echo "File A_sh"
  }
```

**C_sh Contains:-**

```
  . A_Sh # Source File
  . B_sh # Source File
```

Now from C_sh i want to use `showPid` of A_sh as well as B_sh, how can I do that?

Do we have concept of namespace or can I do something like `A_sh::showPid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. When you source `B.sh` after `A.sh`, B's function replaces A's function because they have the same name. To get around this you will have to rename your functions. Alternatively, you can source the appropriate file just before you call function, but I wouldn't recommend doing this.